# Position a node along a line, without \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I have a line going from `(0,0)` to `(4,4)`. I want to place a node along this line, 75% "away" from the (0,0) coordinate (the starting point).

All methods I have seen thus far to achieve this suggest to do

```
\draw (0,0) -- (4,4) node [pos=0.75] (TextNode) {text};
```

I.e., the line and the node are defined together.

Suppose I first draw the line, how can I now insert *a new `\node` command* so that it inherits the "data" of the ALREADY drawn line and then places the node along it, 75% "away"?

What I envision is something like

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,4) node [] (line) {};
\node (TextNode) at (line) [pos=0.75] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but the `[pos=0.75]` has no effect and the node is rather positioned at `(0,0)`.

Comment: Perhaps `\path (0,0) -- (4,4) node [pos=0.75] {text};`? Or using `calc` library?

Comment: The **only** drawback for using path is that it will be included in the bounding box.  See `pgfinterruptboundingbox` (pp. 1079-1080).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. With a `\path` over the line and drawing a `node [pos=0.75]`.
2. Using `calc` library with the syntax `($(A)!0.75!(B)$)` that specifies a point between A and B with a distance ratio 0.75:0.25.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,4);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\path (A) -- (B) node [blue,pos=0.75] {text at 0.75};
\node[red] at ($(A)!0.25!(B)$) {text at 0.25};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The calc approach is what I was looking for.